# Django filter form not displaying

Tags: django-filter, django-3.0

I'm using django filters but I can't get the filter form to actually render on the page, only the submit button is showing. If I inspect the element, nothing else seems to be being sent to the template. THere is no error message or anything, I don't know where to go from here, how do I get the actual form to show,

filter.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import django_filters
from .models import Project


class ProjectFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['user', 'title']
```

views.py:

```
def search_view(request):
    project_list = Project.objects.all()
    project_filter = ProjectFilter(request.GET, queryset=(project_list)
    return render(request, 'project_portal/filter.html', {'filter': project_filter})
```

urls.py:

```
path('search/', search_view, name='search'),
```

html:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div>
  <form method="get">
    {{ filter.form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit"/>
  </form>
  {% for user in filter.qs %}
  {{ user.title }}
  {% endfor %}
</div
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your error ...
==> project_filter = ProjectFilter(request.GET, queryset=(project_list)
must be :
project_filter = ProjectFilter(request.GET, queryset=project_list)

Comment: Thank you, I struggled all night with this, and finally deleted the whole process in a bid to being blind to my own work, but I'm fairly certain the extra "(" was a typo when posting unfortunately as django, I think would fail with an syntax error.